# Track Mobile Device Within Premises

Tags: mobile, android, iphone, geolocation

My brother is working as fresher in one IT organisation in network department. His company is building mobile applications so they have more than 100 mobile devices within premises and more than 500 employees.

Every day they are picking devices for their projects and many of them are forgetting to return it back. The network admin has assigned him a duty to collect it from every one before leaving office for the day in the evening. Due to this duty he is always coming late at home. He needs to search devices on each 5 floors and it takes almost 3 to 4 hours.

Is there any technology, app or devices available that can solve this his daily problem. I will suggest it to his Network admin. I have searched many MDM (Good dynamics and others) and device tracker like TrackR Bravo Bravo, ITag smart etc. Please suggest, It can save some ones daily hours and he can spent more time with his family.

Can we identify device location using wi-fi?

Comment: This really sounds like a management issue. There needs to be a solution promoted higher up. What if you install a tracker, and someone takes the device home, or locks it in a drawer? What's the procedure? How are you supposed to find a device based on the *floor* of a building? Geo-location isn't going to help.

Comment: Thinking about this, I would install an app that allows me to trigger the device to set the volume at max and play a constant sound. If someone took it home, they'd be embarrassed. If it was in  the building, I'd know physically where it was.

Comment: There are a lot of different questions here.  1.  You are asking for product recommendations, which are off-topic.  2.  You are asking if you can identify a device's location using WiFi, and the answer is "yes". But again, providing further details turns it into a product recommendation.  Pick one main question, and search for answers to that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how precise you want to locate them. There is no commercial solution that can do this on premise that I´m aware of(Because GPS etc. suck indoors).

What comes to my mind is triangulating them with several wifi antennas in a selfmade solution. Your brother would have to set up several wifi antennas in the building that are in monitor mode and report to central station. As long as all devices have wifi enabled and you know their MAC Address(or wifi can be turned on remotly by MDM) you can triangulate them

For Example (please forgive me my non existant Paint skills):

[image: AP Scetch]

You check all your APs in Monitor Mode and the MAC adress of the device you´re looking for is recognized by AP1-3

- AP1 gets a damping strenght of -50db
- AP2 gets a damping strenght of -40db
- AP3 gets a damping strenght of -45db

Now you need a little estimation because the signal strenght depends on things like wall thickness etc but you can take a max and min lenght for any given strenght (+/-3 meter of what you expect for example). 
In this example AP1 is in a part of the office with no thik walls, etc. AP2 is in a small office with concrete walls and AP3 is positioned somwhere in the hallway (therefor the variance in min/max distance).

Now you´ve got 3 min/max lines for the given 3 APs and they only overlap in the area marked green which is the location of the device.

I know this approach is far from precise but I think if you script and test everything properly (especially the variance in estimated lenght) this would be able to locate quite precisely.